# How can I create a Permission that is limited to just one TargetGroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

How can I create a Permission (that grants permission to invoke a certain lambda function) that is limited to just one TargetGroup?

It might sound simple but the problem has a couple of different complications:

- Without the `SourceArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup` part in the example below, I assume that the permissions will allow ALL TargetGroups to invoke MyLambda and not just the one I intend (correct?).
- I need to keep `DependsOn: LambdaInvokePermission` on the TargetGroup, because otherwise the launch will sometimes fail when deploying from scratch (this happens if the TargetGroup happens to be created before the Permission, because then the TargetGroup does not have permission to invoke the lambda yet and the whole launch will fail).
- By adding `SourceArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup` as in the example below, I introduce a circular dependency which is a no-go.

```
  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    DependsOn: LambdaInvokePermission
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: false
      TargetType: lambda
      Targets:
        - Id: !GetAtt MyLambda.Arn

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambda.Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
```

I also tried giving the TargetGroup an explicit name and then construct the SourceArn statically (in order to avoid the explicit circular dependency in my template), but it will not work because [TargetGroups always get some random string appended to the end of their ARN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231191).

Any ideas?

(This question was [originally posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63832821/948942), but I got feedback that it was better suited here.)

Answer (score 2):

So after being in touch with the support at AWS, it seems like I wasn't that far off after all. Their [recommended solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/handling-circular-dependency-errors-in-aws-cloudformation/) is to give the TargetGroup an explicit name and then use a wildcard at the end of the SourceArn to get around the random string that gets appended to the ARN of TargetGroups. Here's an example:

```
MyTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  DependsOn: LambdaInvokePermission
  Properties:
    Name: my-target-group
    HealthCheckEnabled: false
    TargetType: lambda
    Targets:
      - Id: !GetAtt MyLambda.Arn

LambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambda.Arn
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:elasticloadbalancing:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:targetgroup/my-target-group/*"
```

The downside of this approach is that by explicitly naming resources it gets harder to modify them in the future. So if you have any alternative ideas you are very welcome to share them.